# Swift URL resolvingSymlinksInPath() behaves unexpectedly

Tags: swift, linux, ubuntu, debian, symlink

I was playing with Swift to build a little toy app to control the speed of the fan of my computer (I'm on Debian, Swift 5.9). However I stumbled across something really weird (at least to me). I had to list the content of a directory, which is a symlink. I know that `FileManager.contentsOfDirectory()` method doesn't follow symlinks. So I wanted to resolve symlinks directly calling the `.resolvingSymlinksInPath()` method of the URL class. Here is what I did:

```swift
import Foundation

let fm = FileManager.default

print(URL(fileURLWithPath: "/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon6").resolvingSymlinksInPath())
```

I know that `/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon6` is a symlink as

```
byrth@utah ~> ls -l /sys/class/hwmon/                                                   (base) 
lrwxrwxrwx - root 10 Dec 16:01 hwmon0 -> ../../devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0A:00/power_supply/BAT0/hwmon0
lrwxrwxrwx - root 10 Dec 16:01 hwmon1 -> ../../devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.4/0000:03:00.0/nvme/nvme0/hwmon1
lrwxrwxrwx - root 10 Dec 16:01 hwmon2 -> ../../devices/platform/coretemp.0/hwmon/hwmon2
lrwxrwxrwx - root 10 Dec 16:01 hwmon3 -> ../../devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/ACPI0003:00/power_supply/AC/hwmon3
lrwxrwxrwx - root 10 Dec 16:01 hwmon4 -> ../../devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone4/hwmon4
lrwxrwxrwx - root 10 Dec 16:01 hwmon5 -> ../../devices/platform/dell_smm_hwmon/hwmon/hwmon5
lrwxrwxrwx - root 10 Dec 16:01 hwmon6 -> ../../devices/platform/USBC000:00/power_supply/ucsi-source-psy-USBC000:001/hwmon6
lrwxrwxrwx - root 10 Dec 16:01 hwmon7 -> ../../devices/virtual/thermal/thermal_zone6/hwmon7
```

Strangely enough, when I run my program the output is simply

```
byrth@utah /tmp> swift my-program.swift                                                    (base) 
file:///sys/class/hwmon/hwmon6/
byrth@utah /tmp>                                                                           (base)
```

To investigate further I tried to run `strace ./my-swift-compiled-program`, to see which syscalls the program called and this was the result:

```
... other strace information ...
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon6", {st_mode=S_IFLNK|0777, st_size=0, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon6", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}, 0) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon6", {st_mode=S_IFLNK|0777, st_size=0, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon6", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}, 0) = 0
readlink("/sys", 0x56166c31b410, 4097)  = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
readlink("/sys/class", 0x56166c31b410, 4097) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
readlink("/sys/class/hwmon", 0x56166c31b410, 4097) = -1 EINVAL (Invalid argument)
readlink("/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon6", "../../devices/platform/USBC000:0"..., 4097) = 81
getcwd("/tmp", 1024)                    = 5
readlink("/devices", 0x7ffc5feea050, 1023) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon6", {st_mode=S_IFLNK|0777, st_size=0, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon6", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}, 0) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon6", {st_mode=S_IFLNK|0777, st_size=0, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon6", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0755, st_size=0, ...}, 0) = 0
newfstatat(1, "", {st_mode=S_IFCHR|0620, st_rdev=makedev(0x88, 0), ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
write(1, "file:///sys/class/hwmon/hwmon6/\n", 32file:///sys/class/hwmon/hwmon6/
) = 32
exit_group(0)                           = ?
```

So apparently it understands the `/sys/class/hwmon/hwmon6` is a symlink but than it tries to resolve it relatively to the current working directory (that in this case is `/tmp`). Is this a bug or it's just me that I don't understand something?

Thanks in advance for any help ;-)

Comment: Hmmm I can't reproduce. Have a look at what I tried: https://gist.github.com/amomchilov/b84d93a9097c92773a17b934dea67df2 This might be a platform specific issue. Could you try running that same demo on your machine? (Changing your username/home folder, of course)

Comment: Yes I can. Same problem It doesn't resolve it correctly and prints file:///home/gp/Desktop/demo/link.txt

Comment: Hmmm I strongly suspect it's a platform-specific quirk. In this case, from the Foundation implementation on Linux [`swift-corelibs-foundation`](https://github.com/apple/swift-corelibs-foundation), which (very frustratingly) is different from the proprietary implementation that Apple uses in its OSes. Perhaps it's worth snooping into how its resolves symlinks, to see if that's where the bugs might be?

Comment: Apple is shifting to a new pure-Swift re-implementation of Foundation [`swift-foundation`](https://github.com/apple/swift-foundation), which will be used in its OSes. See https://www.swift.org/blog/future-of-foundation/ Perhaps it doesn't have the same bug. Can you try it?

Comment: Hey @Beowulf, did you even end up figuring out what's going on here?

Comment: Nope. I figured there's not much interest in mantaining Swift working on linux. I switched to something else.

Comment: Ahhh, I'm sorry to hear that. It was really rough, especially with the schism between the legacy Objective-C-implemented Foundation that used to ship with apple devices, and swift-corelibs-foundation on linux. They're fixing that now, as they're all moving to a new Swift-first rewrite. Should be getting better.

Comment: I poked around the implementation, and it just calls out to `realpath`, which shouldn't be based off the cwd, from what I understand. Not sure what's going on here :/